# Code example of comparing times in different time zone in C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Can anyone explain why the `comparisonTime` variable is calculated using the logic like below, especially using the lines below:

`local.GetAdjustmentRules()[local.GetAdjustmentRules().Length - 1].DaylightDelta;`

and

`TimeSpan comparisonTime = time + (offset - tz.BaseUtcOffset).Negate() + (delta - storeDelta).Negate();`

[The TimeSpan structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/choosing-between-datetime#the-timespan-structure)

```
 using System;
    
    public struct StoreInfo
    {
       public String store;
       public TimeZoneInfo tz;
       public TimeSpan open;
       public TimeSpan close;
    
       public bool IsOpenNow()
       {
          return IsOpenAt(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);
       }
    
       public bool IsOpenAt(TimeSpan time)
       {
          TimeZoneInfo local = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
          TimeSpan offset = TimeZoneInfo.Local.BaseUtcOffset;
    
          // Is the store in the same time zone?
          if (tz.Equals(local)) {
             return time >= open & time <= close;
          }
          else {
             TimeSpan delta = TimeSpan.Zero;
             TimeSpan storeDelta = TimeSpan.Zero;
    
             // Is it daylight saving time in either time zone?
             if (local.IsDaylightSavingTime(DateTime.Now.Date + time))
                delta = local.GetAdjustmentRules()[local.GetAdjustmentRules().Length - 1].DaylightDelta;
    
             if (tz.IsDaylightSavingTime(TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now.Date + time, local, tz)))
                storeDelta = tz.GetAdjustmentRules()[tz.GetAdjustmentRules().Length - 1].DaylightDelta;
    
             TimeSpan comparisonTime = time + (offset - tz.BaseUtcOffset).Negate() + (delta - storeDelta).Negate();
             return comparisonTime >= open & comparisonTime <= close;
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Just in case, have you tried using the DateTimeOffset ? It's a type that contains the timezone in addition to the date+time infos. So it can do most of this work for you normally.

Comment: @Arcord That's Incorrect. It contains the *offset* which while similar to the timezone is actually quite different. OP: Assuming that this isn't the *only* place you have such logic I'd suggest not using any of the built in .NET time zone/translation utilities and rather use something like nodatime instead. (In fact, considering Timezones calculations are so easy to get wrong especially in .NET, I *might* even argue for Nodatime just for a single use) You'll thank yourself for it later

Comment: Indeed you right. But from the timezone you can extract the offset?

Comment: Also note that `TimeZoneInfo.Local` can be manipulated by the system settings. In fact depending on whether "Automatically adjust for daylight savings" is checked in control panel the local time zone info could always return `false` for `IsDaylightSavings` and a zero length array for `local.GetAdjustmentRules`. So unless you have complete control of the system, I'd advise being careful how you use the above (and again suggest a third party lib)

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 please can you suggest a 3rd party lib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`TimeZoneInfo.GetAdjustmentRules`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.getadjustmentrules?view=netcore-3.1) returns an array of [`AdjustmentRule`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.adjustmentrule?view=netcore-3.1) objects, each of which identifies time adjustments made for daylight savings time. This includes the start and end date as well as the amount of time the clocks are adjusted and when these rules go into effect (Rules change, for example the US used to have an April-October cycle but now its March-November). The rules are *generally* ordered by oldest to newest.

The code in question is incorrectly (see below) finding the last rule in the list (`local.GetAdjustmentRules()[local.GetAdjustmentRules().Length - 1]`) and figuring out how much the time is changed by that rule (`DaylightDelta`--in the US this is typically one hour, but parts of the world may adjust by other values such as 30 minutes)

The second bit of code you inquire about attempts to *normalize* the passed in time if either/both zone is currently respecting daylight savings. It does this by adding the differences in the two `DaylightDelta` (the amout the clocks get moved ahead/behind) and the two `BaseUtcOffset` (the zone's non-DST difference from UTC). It then adds that to the original time and uses that for comparisons instead.

The code is incorrect for several reasons (and this is perhaps not exhaustive):

- It assumes the adjustment rules are ordered. The MSDN documentation says that they are "generally ordered" but makes no guarantees
- It assumes that the last adjustment rule is the current one. As noted above, they aren't ordered. But they might also contain future rules that are not yet effective
- It does not account for times that are near to midnight and might roll over to the next day. This holds true for both branches of the code. While it's possibly unlikely for a store to be open passed midnight it is a definite possibility (I don't know your business rules). If the store is open from 8am to 2am, the tests will fail for 1am when it should succeed
- Similarly, for a store where the hours pass midnight, the daylight savings calculation could prove even more inaccurate if the times fall at the DST boundaries
- `TimeZoneInfo.Local` can be manipulated by the system settings. In fact depending on whether "Automatically adjust for daylight savings" is checked in control panel the local time zone info could always return `false` for `IsDaylightSavings` and a zero length array for `local.GetAdjustmentRules`. This means that the same code run on two computers could return different results even if they are sitting next to each other!
- It assumes that the system is up to date. Depending on where in the world you are, daylight savings rules may change often. In cases like these, it is common to have an Operating System that doesn't have all of the latest information.

Dealing with time zones and daylight savings is tough. The rules are changing all the time and the tools in the framework are quite clunky and difficult to work with (assuming you can understand them). What's worse is that they aren't always up to date!

I'm not going to *attempt* to provide you with fixed code. I tend to leave anything related to time and DST calculations to the experts. I'd highly suggest looking into the [NodaTime](https://nodatime.org/) library for calculations such as these. It's entirely devoted to the subject matter and the timezone rules are regularly updated. Their [Why do we exist](https://nodatime.org/2.0.x/userguide/rationale) page calls out some of the things I've mentioned above as does [this blog post](https://blog.nodatime.org/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html?m=1) written by one of the library's authors, Jon Skeet.